# Excluding filters from a particular action

Tags: struts2, servlet-filters, struts2-namespace

Here's the situation. All the actions in my `struts.xml` file share the same namespace. I have a bunch of filters applied to the whole namespace in web.xml. Now I've added another action and I want only one of those filters applied to this new action. Is there a common practice to follow here? Do I need to create a different namespace for this new action or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created a different namespace for this action and then mapped the filter to it.